# Distribute numbers with MPI Scatter - error

Tags: c++, c, openmpi

I did a simple example to understand how `MPI_Scatter` works. I want to distribute two integer numbers for each process. 
But i get always a segmentation error. What is wrong in my code.

```
void do_work(int val, int rank){
    printf("I am rank number %d and i got the randval %d.\n",rank,val);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

    int size, rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int M=2; 
    int N = M*size; 

    int * input;
    int * recv;

    if(rank==0){
        input = (int*)calloc(N, sizeof(int));
        for(int i=0;i<N; ++i) input[i]=10 + i;
    }

    recv = (*int)calloc(M, sizeof(int));

    MPI_Scatter(&input[0], M, MPI_INT,&recv[0],M, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    for(int i=0; i<M; ++i) do_work(recv[i],rank);

    free(input);
    free(recv);
    MPI_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why `c++`? Where does the segfault occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem comes from:

```
int size, rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
```

`rand` and `size` are swapped, it should have been:

```
int size, rank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
```

Comment: Ohhh you are a hero! True, i lost so many hours because of this stupid error! Thanks for your quick help.